# In Visual Studio Code, I want to pass a parameter(e.g. -i) to the Python interpreter when I debug/run my code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to learn Python programming, I would want to run my code then play with it using the "-i" option in Python Interpreter. However when I'm defining "args": ["-i"] in my launch.json file the -i becomes an argument for my program instead.

Is there some way that I could pass the "-i" as an argument to Python Interpreter in visual studio Code?

e.g.:

```
# test.py
dict = [{'name': 'AA', 'price': 32.2, 'shares': 100},
 {'name': 'IBM', 'price': 91.1, 'shares': 50},
 {'name': 'CAT', 'price': 83.44, 'shares': 150}]
```

run

```
>python.exe -i test.py
>>>dict = [{'name': 'AA', 'price': 32.2, 'shares': 100},
 {'name': 'IBM', 'price': 91.1, 'shares': 50},
 {'name': 'CAT', 'price': 83.44, 'shares': 150}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's supported for Python, but try using `runtimeArgs` instead of `Args`.